# Using Count and date

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I have the problem where I need to select records as this:

If the # of Job "Plumbers" > 3 (Per House) , return only 03 records, with the plumbers order by "hire date".

If there are more than 03 records per "House", I need to return ALWAYS 03 records with the JOb = Plumber , order by "hire date", per "house".

If there are 02 PLumbers and the others are "helpers", return the 02 PLumbers + the oldest (based on hire date) Helper.

If there are no Plumbers, return the Helpers (only 03!) based on "Hire Date" , oldest first.

So here is a data sample:

```
House   Name    Job      hire date
Yellow  John    Plumber  1/1/15
Yellow  Mary    Plumber  1/2/15
Yellow  Kyle    Helper   1/10/15
Yellow  Vince   Helper   1/12/15
Blue    Mark    Plumber  1/1/15
Blue    Janet   Plumber  1/5/15
Blue    Joyce   Plumber  1/20/15
Blue    Jim     Plumber  1/4/15
Red     Jones   Plumber  1/8/15
Red     Joe     Helper   1/7/15
Red     Michael Helper   1/2/15
Red     Paul    Helper   1/15/15
Red     Bill    Helper   1/9/15
```

The results I need to see are:

```
Yellow  John    Plumber 1/1/15
Yellow  Mary    Plumber 1/2/15
Yellow  Kyle    Helper  1/10/15

Blue    Mark    Plumber 1/1/15
Blue    Jim     Plumber 1/4/15
Blue    Janet   Plumber 1/5/15

Red     Michael Helper  1/2/15
Red     Joe     Helper  1/7/15    
Red     Jones   Plumber 1/8/15
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: What if there's only one Plumber?

Comment: You're right. sorry about this. This is a SQL Server problem.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the correct result based on your example data:

```
select *
from 
 (
   select House, Name, Job, hire_date,
      row_number() 
      over (partition by House
            order by Job desc, hire_date) as rn
   from tab
 ) as dt
where rn <= 3
```

The row_number is assigned based on 'Plumbers' first, then 'Helpers', each with ascending dates.

Comment: Perfect! I was going on the route of using Count() and Group by, but "partition" and Row NUmber () did the trick.